# Elixir and continuation-passing style

Tags: elixir, continuations

Does Elixir have anything like Scheme's `call-with-current-continuation`? Is there a way to capture the waiting stack frames and store it in a variable for later use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erlang/Elixir does not have the classical call/cc you would find in Scheme-like languages.

You can just write CPS-style code in Elixir, though. You can capture the current closure in a function and pass that around and manually slice your computations that way.

Edit: I have just implemented an ANF transformation[1] in CPS style. It might serve as inspiration.

[1] https://gist.github.com/m1dnight/053494cdc35b89af6fe0b3b63283abd0

Answer (score 0):

I've made a library[1] that experiments with delimited continuations in Elixir, in case that's of interest to anyone.  It's possible to play with some examples, and it was even possible to implement some effects using that, like mutable state and recoverable exceptions.

[1] https://github.com/thalesmg/campinas